# ATXmega128A1 USARTD0 RX not working, but F0 does with the same code

Tags: uart, atxmega

I have a problem with my atxmega128a1. I wrote a code using 3 usart interfaces. The init code is the same, but only two of the ports works fine. 
The problem is with USARTD0 (and I tried USARTD1, but also fails)
The sympthom is the next: first USARTD0 inited to 9600bps, and after a few transmission, it has to init again to 115200bps. After setting up again to he new baud, it stops recieving. I can send via TX, but USART_RXCIF_bm never set. 
It is so strange, beause the same code works fine with other ports. I have checked my code, and wiring many times.
Does anyone have any idea? I dig in erratas, alternative functions, etc. but haven't found any useful yet.
Thanks in advance, and sorry for my rough English.

```
void uart_init_d0(long baudrate){   
usart_rs232_options_t options = {
        .baudrate = baudrate,
        .charlength = USART_CHSIZE_8BIT_gc,
        .paritytype = USART_PMODE_DISABLED_gc,
        .stopbits = 0 // 0=>1 stop bit
    };

    PORTD.DIRCLR   = PIN2_bm;   // (RXD1) input
    PORTD.DIRSET   = PIN3_bm;   // (TXD1) output

    sysclk_enable_module(SYSCLK_PORT_D, PR_USART0_bm);
    usart_init_rs232(USART_BAY2, &options);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code, and the usart modules are correct. (Unfortunately my problem comes from anouther IC on the board, but that is anouther question.)